# How do I Black Hole a standard Go Network Request

Tags: go, networking, proxy, routes

I am experimenting with the Go's [httpuitls.ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) and [http.HandleFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandleFunc). I am trying to create a way to Black Hole certain routes in my simple proxy as shown below. How do I get the http library to completely throw out my request without responding or sending a disconnect?

This example hopefully clarifies what I mean. See the `/toss` route below.

```go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    origin, _ := url.Parse("https://www.example.com:443/")

    director := func(req *http.Request) {
        req.URL.Scheme = "https"
        req.URL.Host = origin.Host
        req.Host = origin.Host
    }

    proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}

    http.HandleFunc("/toss", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // What goes here to Black Hole this request??
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

---

Adding a little context to the question, the ultimate goal here is to use this proxy with a destructive testing tool. The idea being that the clients are never given a response to certain routes and it allows the user of the tool to see how their applications will handle this.

Answer (score 2):

[Hijack](https://godoc.org/net/http#Hijacker) the connection from the server. Close the connection.

```
    if h, ok := w.(http.Hijacker); ok {
        c, _, err := h.Hijack()
        if err == nil {
            c.Close()
            return
        }
    }
    // Fallback to bad request.
    http.Error(w, "bad request", http.StatusBadRequest)
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0pYk8s-iVbz).

Hijack can fail because of middleware blocking access to the server's response writer, middleware wrote to the connection before then handler was called or because the the connection is using the http/2 protocol.  The call to http.Error is a fallback for those scenarios.

There's no other option for abandoning the connection without doing something at the network layer.

Hijacking the connection without also closing the connection leaks file descriptors. The file descriptors may be eventually closed by low-level connection's finalizer, but the process may breach the file descriptor limit before that happens.

Comment: Seems promising, but when I try it I'm getting "$ curl http://localhost:8080/toss
curl: (52) Empty reply from server." Are you able to get it to work with the code above? What I'm looking to happen is just have the curl get stuck until it times out. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: @thinktt, The only way to truly black hole packets is at the network level. The server is going to correctly handle TCP regardless of what the handler does.

Comment: @thinktt what if you hijack and then return without closing the response? I think after a hijack you're expected to clean up the connection yourself, so not closing it might have the effect you want.

Comment: @maxm I tried your idea and it worked. The issue is, after thinking about JimB's response Steffen's answer below, I'm concerned this will eventually blow up. It's fine for testing with a curl but if I send a million request things are probably going to get ugly for the Go server and maybe even the VM it's running on. I'm thinking I need to find a way as suggested below to drop the connection and not respond on the network level.

Comment: @thinktt Hijacking the connection without also closing the connection leaks file descriptors. The file descriptors may be eventually closed by low-level connection's finalizer, but the process may breach the file descriptor limit before that happens.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get the http library to completely throw out my request without responding or sending a disconnect?

This requirement would essentially mean that the socket to the client stays alive, eating up resources at the server. Thus this kind of black-holing would be a bad idea. When interacting with the OS kernel or firewall it might be possible to close the socket locally only without the client noticing. But this will get very tricky and system depdend since for quickly cleaning up local resources it is usually required that the system got the reply from the client that the socket was closed on their end too etc.

An easier way would be to respond with a redirect to a different port on the same host and then simply drop (not reject) all traffic to this port at the firewall. Clients will usually blindly follow the redirect and than hang there until the connection attempt times out. This will thwart clients without eating up resources at the server.

Comment: Your concern about the server resources makes sense and is something that had crossed my mind. Judging by your reply and the comments above it does sound like I will need to move to network layer to accomplish this appropriately. I appreciate the reply.